# Jenkins - Trigger build if file changes http archive

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to trigger a build if a http file changes?
My url: http://archive.foo/latest/application_build_001.img

The name of the image file changes to eg. application_build_002.img when a new build is avalible.

I tried the URL Trigger plugin for jenkins with "Check the last modification Date" and "*" in the URL, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to specify a wildcard like `*` in the URL Trigger plugin (or in HTTP generally), so that won't work.

If you visit http://archive.foo/latest/ is there a list of all `*.img` files there?
If so, you could use that as the trigger URL, since that *will* change each time you upload a new file, or rename an existing file.

Otherwise, you could write a `latest.txt` file to that directory (or elsewhere) with the latest `.img` filename in it.  Then you can use that `latest.txt` URL as the trigger.

If *that's* not possible, you could try looking at the [Script Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) and write your own custom check to determine whether a new file exists.

Comment: Yes, there is a list. Like an apache index that lists all the files. How do i use the URL Trigger plugin to check if there is changes in the folder? i Does not seem to for me with http://archive.foo/latest/ configured as the url and "Check the last modification Date" ticked off in "URL Response Check"

Comment: Looking at that plugin's wiki page, it seems like you should be able to check "Inspect URL content", and then choose "Monitor a change of the content" with your list URL.